# How to avoid duplicating strings in a row created by foreach loop?

Tags: php

After trying some methods without success, I must give up, and ask this here.

So I have an array **$product_var_tpl_list = array();** the output looks like this:

```
Shop1m  |  Pruduct 12  
Shop1m  |  Product 366 
Shop1m  |  Product 66 
Shop3a  |  Product 89 
Shop3a  |  Product 5   
Shop55  |  Product 6
```

I want to avoid dublicating strings from column 1 - the output must be like this:

```
Shop1m  |  Pruduct 12  
        |  Product 366
        |  Product 66  
Shop3a  |  Product 89 
        |  Product 5  
Shop55  |  Product 6
```

The PHP code is:

```
                    $product_var_tpl_list = array();
                    foreach ($order->product_list as $product) {
                        $price = Product::getPriceStatic((int)$product['id_product'], false, ($product['id_product_attribute'] ? (int)$product['id_product_attribute'] : null), 6, null, false, true, $product['cart_quantity'], false, (int)$order->id_customer, (int)$order->id_cart, (int)$order->{Configuration::get('PS_TAX_ADDRESS_TYPE')});
                        $price_wt = Product::getPriceStatic((int)$product['id_product'], true, ($product['id_product_attribute'] ? (int)$product['id_product_attribute'] : null), 2, null, false, true, $product['cart_quantity'], false, (int)$order->id_customer, (int)$order->id_cart, (int)$order->{Configuration::get('PS_TAX_ADDRESS_TYPE')});

                        $product_price = Product::getTaxCalculationMethod() == PS_TAX_EXC ? Tools::ps_round($price, 2) : $price_wt;

                        //here is data about the seller
                        $idProduct = (int)$product['id_product'];
                        $SellerInfoOverride = Db::getInstance()->executeS('SELECT * FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'wk_mp_seller_product`  WHERE `id_ps_product` = '.(int) $idProduct);
                        foreach ($SellerInfoOverride as $key => $value) {
                            $sellerid = $value['id_seller'];
                            //$seller = $mpSeller->getSeller($value['id_seller'], $this->context->language->id);
                            $SellerInfoDetails = Db::getInstance()->executeS('SELECT * FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'wk_mp_seller`  WHERE `id_seller` = '.(int) $sellerid);
                            foreach ($SellerInfoDetails as $key => $value) {
                                $seller_name = $value['shop_name_unique'];
                            }
                        }

                        $product_var_tpl = array(

                            'reference' => $seller_name,
                            'name' => $product['name'].(isset($product['attributes']) ? ' - '.$product['attributes'] : ''),
                            'unit_price' => Tools::displayPrice($product_price, $this->context->currency, false),
                            'price' => Tools::displayPrice($product_price * $product['quantity'], $this->context->currency, false),
                            'quantity' => $product['quantity'],
                            'customization' => array()

                        );


                        $customized_datas = Product::getAllCustomizedDatas((int)$order->id_cart);
                        if (isset($customized_datas[$product['id_product']][$product['id_product_attribute']])) {
                            $product_var_tpl['customization'] = array();
                            foreach ($customized_datas[$product['id_product']][$product['id_product_attribute']][$order->id_address_delivery] as $customization) {
                                $customization_text = '';
                                if (isset($customization['datas'][Product::CUSTOMIZE_TEXTFIELD])) {
                                    foreach ($customization['datas'][Product::CUSTOMIZE_TEXTFIELD] as $text) {
                                        $customization_text .= $text['name'].': '.$text['value'].'<br />';
                                    }
                                }

                                if (isset($customization['datas'][Product::CUSTOMIZE_FILE])) {
                                    $customization_text .= sprintf(Tools::displayError('%d image(s)'), count($customization['datas'][Product::CUSTOMIZE_FILE])).'<br />';
                                }

                                $customization_quantity = (int)$product['customization_quantity'];

                                $product_var_tpl['customization'][] = array(
                                    'customization_text' => $customization_text,
                                    'customization_quantity' => $customization_quantity,
                                    'quantity' => Tools::displayPrice($customization_quantity * $product_price, $this->context->currency, false)
                                );
                            }
                        }

                        $product_var_tpl_list[] = $product_var_tpl;
                        // Check if is not a virutal product for the displaying of shipping
                        if (!$product['is_virtual']) {
                            $virtual_product &= false;
                        }
                    } // end foreach ($products)

                    // this will sort the output by alphabetical order based on reference value
                    usort($product_var_tpl_list, function($a, $b) {  
                            return strcmp($a['reference'], $b['reference']);
                    });
```

Comment: "The output of it looks like this" - output how? When you run what specific code? Is the left side the keys and the right the values? Try to condense your code to just the specific problem - that's a lot of code you've posted for a relatively simple question.

Comment: Assuming you're just iterating over your items in a loop, all you need to do is keep track of the `last shop` name, and if it matches the current item's `shop` name you output an empty string. Otherwise, output the `last shop` name and update its value.

Comment: `So I have an array` better show us array columns and how You output it, instead of giving long code example `The PHP code is` which makes SO users to read the long code in search of that place where You output it.

Comment: _the output must be like this..._ Do you expect an array as output?

Comment: Sorry, the reason I added all the PHP code for the ARRAY "product_var_tpl_list" is that I have asked a different question regarding this array, and I tried to mak eit simple but I was asked many times to show all the code. So, i thought it will be better if now I will show all the code for this array

Answer (score 1):

My answer will be generic.

You've an array with `reference`, `name` columns, where reference is shop.

Group them:

```php
$sellerProducts = [];
foreach($product_var_tpl AS $product) :
  if (!isset($sellerProducts[$product['reference']])) {
    $sellerProducts[$product['reference']] = [];
  }
  $sellerProducts[$product['reference']][] = $product;
endforeach;

$smarty->assign('sellerProducts', $sellerProducts);
```

and then output it:

```php
foreach($sellerProducts AS $seller => $products) :
  print($seller.":\n");
  foreach($products AS $product) :
    print($product['name']."\n");
  endforeach;
  print("\n\n");
endforeach;
```

OR Smarty template example ([foreach manual](https://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.foreach)):

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Seller</th>
    <th>Product name</th>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
  {foreach from=$sellerProducts key=$seller item=$products}
    <tr>
      <td>{$seller}</td>
      <td>
        <ol>
        {foreach from=$products item=$product}
          <li>{$product.name}</li>
        {/foreach}
        </ol>
      </td>
    </tr>
  {/foreach}
  </tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think your way is closer to what I need. However I need some help to make it work. First of all how can your example work if in my case if the output is made with smarty. {foreach $list as $product} {foreach}

Comment: I've added smarty template example, but how to pass `$sellerProducts` to template it's up to You, cause it's out of scope of Your question. Good luck.

Comment: thanks for your help! I've tried many way of make it work but in the end I get empty row in results. I tried to change the array name to product_var_tpl_list, I also placed your php code in foreach loop and out side of it... no luck....  I even dont know what to ask further. I am confused about it.

Comment: look other parts of Your code and find how to pass variable to smarty template. (seems like it's not written by You, otherwise You would not ask so much).

Comment: no, of course not by me. I am trying to make some modifications to a Prestashop file. And I am not a PHP guru :)

Comment: `$smarty->assign('sellerProducts', $sellerProducts);`

Answer (score 1):

As the comments have pointed out above, there are a few pieces of your question that are a bit vague, mainly the structure of your array data. Because of this, I've made some assumptions in my answer below. Note that while it works, you may need to modify it slightly to fit your particular use case:

```
/*
 *  Original Data
 */
$data = [
    [ "key" => "Shop1m", "value" => "Product 12" ],    
    [ "key" => "Shop1m", "value" => "Product 366" ],
    [ "key" => "Shop1m", "value" => "Product 66" ],
    [ "key" => "Shop3a", "value" => "Product 89" ],
    [ "key" => "Shop3a", "value" => "Product 5" ],
    [ "key" => "Shop55", "value" => "Product 6" ]
];

/*
 *  Let's organize the data more like you'd like the output
 *  to be. We'll bring the initial keys to the forefront by
 *  creating a multi-dimensional array where all of the
 *  related products are grouped under their appropriate
 *  key header.
 */
$altered_data = [];

foreach($data as $entry) {
    if(!isset($altered_data[$entry["key"]])) {
        $altered_data[$entry["key"]] = [];
    }
    $altered_data[$entry["key"]][] = $entry["value"];
}

/*
 *  Now we'll output the data. This becomes trivial with a
 *  double "for" loop (i.e. "foreach" + "for" loops) without
 *  the need for keeping track of the previous header.
 */
echo "<table><tbody>";

foreach($altered_data as $key => $value) {
    for($a = 0, $len = count($value); $a < $len; $a++) {
      echo "<tr>";
      echo (0 === $a) ? "<td>" . $key . "</td>" : "<td></td>";
      echo "<td>" . $value[$a] . "</td>";
    }
}

echo "</tbody></table>";
```